# Проблема с char'ом. Java

Tags: java, char

В данном коде, в методе action пользователь должен выбрать одно из действий (+ - / * и т.д) далее, я должен в switch сравнить > Если +, то выполняем такое-то действие и т.д
Занести в переменную act символ у меня вроде как получилось, а как дальше, не знаю

```
package com.company;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class reader {
int a,b,c;
char act;
Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in, "utf-8");
public void scan() {

    System.out.print("Введите число");

    a = scn.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Введите второе число");
    b = scn.nextInt();
}
public char action (){
    System.out.print("Выберите действие: +, -, *, /");
    act = scn.next().charAt(0);
    switch (act){
    case 1: c = a+b;
    }


    return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Почему бы вам не попробовать

```
   switch (act)
   {
       case '+': c = a + b; break;
       case '-': c = a - b; break;
       //...
   }
```